# How can I make a bootable usb from ubuntu? I want windows 10 Back

Tags: dual-boot, usb, windows

When trying to dual boot with win10 something went wrong and down into the Linux world I came. I like Linux, but a more familiar with windows. I want to iso windows, but cant find anything that will let me, not being on windows, i cant use any of these linux tools. I cant even use unetbootin because of an error message that i posted earlier. Could use some help please

Comment: does this resource help? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringWindows

Answer (score 0):

I use Woeusb to create bootable usb with win10 and it works,I was able to run it and install win10 but you must search to find Woeusb that will work